# Stop Array Shuffle When Do Submit

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, shuffle

I had develop a simple quiz system that allow user generate random question from database. I had use array shuffle to do the random question. My problem is every time when I submit the form, the array will shuffle. Now what I want is I want to stop the shuffle when i submit the form.

```
<?php
$ques_ar = array();
$ques = mysql_query("Select * from quiz");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ques))
{
    $ques_ar[] = $row;
}

shuffle($ques_ar);
echo '<form method="post">';
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($ques_ar); $i++)
{

    echo ".$ques_ar[$i]['question']."?<br>";

    $a=array($ques_ar[$i]['answer'],$ques_ar[$i]['dummy_ans1'], $ques_ar[$i]['dummy_ans2'], $ques_ar[$i]['dummy_ans3']);
    shuffle($a);

    foreach($a as $ram => $value)
    {
        $alp = array("A","B","C","D");
        echo "<input type='radio' name='".$i."' value='".$value."'>".$alp[$ram]." (".$value.")<br>";
    }

        if(isset($_POST[$i]))
        {
            if($_POST[$i] == $ques_ar[$i]['answer'])
            {
                echo "Correct !<br>";
                $score = 1;
            }else{
                echo "Wrong ! <br>";
                $score = 0;
            }
        }
        $total +=$score;


}
echo "<input type='submit' name='sub_ans'>";
echo '</form>';

echo "Score => ".$total." / ".sizeof($ques_ar);

?>
```

Comment: Just move the shuffle

Comment: @rjdownWhat to do if I want to shuffle the question?